# Using Debian linux command 'whereis' to show files without man pages

Tags: linux, bash, unix, debian, man

From the 'whereis' man pages on my Debian/GNU Linux I see:

```
       -u     Search  for  unusual entries.  A file is said to be unusual
              if it does not have one entry of each requested type.  Thus
              `whereis  -m  -u  *'  asks  for  those files in the current
              directory which have no documentation.
```

so I did:

```
root@wheezy:~# cd /bin
root@wheezy:/bin# whereis -um *
```

and i get those lines:

```
...
kmod:
login: /usr/share/man/man3/login.3.gz /usr/share/man/man1/login.1.gz
mkdir: /usr/share/man/man2/mkdir.2.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mkdir.1.gz
mknod: /usr/share/man/man2/mknod.2.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mknod.1.gz
mktemp: /usr/share/man/man3/mktemp.3.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mktemp.1.gz
mount: /usr/share/man/man8/mount.8.gz /usr/share/man/man2/mount.2.gz
ntfsck:
ntfsdump_logfile:
...
```

I understand it correctly shows kmod, ntfsck, and ntfsdump_logfile, etc. for not having man pages, but why it shows the other ones?
Didn't I ask *correctly* for the one without man pages?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you asked for the ones *without* man pages to be *included*, but not for the ones *with* man pages to be *excluded*. This is why `whereis` provides you with a combined list.